# getting name error? total_charge is undefind

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if code == "B":
  based_charge: int(40 * days)
  mileage_charge = driven * .25
  total_charge = mileage_charge + based_charge
```

Comment: You never defined `based_charge`; you only annotated the name. You probably wanted `based_charge = int(40 * days)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you defined what "days" and "driven" is?

Your code should look either like this:

```
if code == "B":
  days = 4 #Example, define some number of days
  driven = 10 #Example, define how much you've driven already
  based_charge = int(40 * days)
  mileage_charge = driven * .25
  total_charge = mileage_charge + based_charge
```

or like this (if you've predefined "days" and "driven":

```
days = 4 #Example, define some number of days
driven = 10 #Example, define how much you've driven already
if code == "B":  
  based_charge = int(40 * days)
  mileage_charge = driven * .25
  total_charge = mileage_charge + based_charge
```